# How to open child component modal from parent by using its key in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, modal-dialog, crud

I am creating my blog where I want to edit the each blog respectively on click of it edit button.
Now modal is opening for respective id but value is not set with `state` value.
That is `componentwillmount` is not properly working.

Any suggestion what i made mistake here ? It will be helpful. 
How can I make this possible witht he current set of code.

//blog.js (Parent component)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';
import {Card, Grid, Cell, Dialog, CardMenu, Button, CardTitle, CardText, CardActions, FABButton, Icon} from'react-mdl';
import { Container, Modal,  ModalHeader, ModalBody, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input,} from 'reactstrap';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getBlog, deleteBlog, updateBlog } from '../../actions/resumeActions';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Loading from './Loading';
import Moment from 'moment';
import BlogModal from "./BlogModal";
import Pagination from "react-js-pagination";
// import EditBlog from "./EditBlog";

class Blogs extends Component{
    initializeReactGA() {
        ReactGA.initialize('UA-132348738-1');
        ReactGA.pageview('/contact');
    }
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
            this.state = {
                modal: false,
                justClicked: null,
                activePage: 1,
                requiredItem : null,
                _id: '',
                blog_short_desc: '',
                blog_name: '',
                blog_desc: '',
                blog_image_link: '',
                blog_by: '',
                blog_by_author: ''
            };
            this.handleOpenDialog = this.handleOpenDialog.bind(this);
              this.handleCloseDialog = this.handleCloseDialog.bind(this);
              this.replaceModalItem = this.replaceModalItem.bind(this);
            this.onTodoChange = this.onTodoChange.bind(this);
        }

    static propTypes = {
        getBlog: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        deleteBlog: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        updateBlog: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        resume: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        loading: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    }

    UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
            value: nextProps.name
        })
    }

    toggle = (id) => {
        this.setState({
            modal: !this.state.modal
        });
    }

    componentWillMount() {
debugger
        this.props.resume["blogs"].map((blog) => {
            this.setState({
                updatable : false,
                _id: blog._id,
                blog_short_desc: blog.blog_short_desc,
                blog_name: blog.blog_name,
                blog_desc: blog.blog_desc,
                blog_image_link: blog.blog_image_link,
                blog_by: blog.blog_by,
                blog_by_author: blog.blog_by_author
            });
        })
    }

    replaceModalItem(id) {
        debugger
        this.setState({
          modal: true,
          requiredItem: id

        });
        debugger
    }

    onTodoChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ 
            [e.target.name] : e.target.value 
        });
    }

    onSubmit = (e, id) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const updatedBlog = {
            blog_short_desc: this.state.blog_short_desc,
            blog_name: this.state.blog_name,
            blog_desc: this.state.blog_desc,
            blog_image_link: this.state.blog_image_link,
            blog_by:  this.props.auth["user"]._id,
            blog_by_author: this.props.auth["user"].name
        }
        //update blog via updateblog action
        this.props.updateBlog(id, updatedBlog, this.props.history);
        alert("Blog updated successfully!");
        //close modal
        e.target.reset();
        this.toggle();
    }

    handleOpenDialog(id) {
        this.setState({
          openDialog: true,
          OpenEditDialog: true,
          justClicked: id

        });
    }

    handleCloseDialog() {
    this.setState({
        openDialog: false
    });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getBlog();
    }

    onDeleteBlogClick = (id) => {
        this.props.deleteBlog(id);
    };

    handlePageChange(pageNumber) {
        this.setState({activePage: pageNumber});
    }

    cardDialog(blogs, user){
        const itemsPerPage = 6; 
        let activeBlogs = blogs.slice (itemsPerPage * this.state.activePage - itemsPerPage, itemsPerPage * this.state.activePage);
        return( 
            <Grid style={{padding: 0, display: 'contents'}}>

                {activeBlogs.map(({ _id, blog_name, blog_desc, blog_image_link, blog_by_author }) => (
                <Cell col={12}>
                    <Dialog open={this.state.openDialog && this.state.justClicked === _id} className="open-dialog">

                        {blog_image_link ?
                            (<CardTitle style={{color: '#fff', height: '176px', backgroundImage: `url(${blog_image_link})`, backgroundPosition: 'center',
                            backgroundSize: 'cover',
                            backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat'}}>{blog_name}</CardTitle>) :

                            (<CardTitle className="card-blog-title-image">{blog_name}</CardTitle>
                            )
                        }
                        <CardText>
                            {blog_desc}
                        </CardText>
                        <CardActions border>
                        <p style={{float:'right', fontWeight:'bold'}}>Author: {blog_by_author}</p>
                        </CardActions>
                        <CardMenu style={{color: '#fff'}}>
                            <FABButton onClick={this.handleCloseDialog} className="close-button" >
                                <Icon name="close" />
                            </FABButton>
                        </CardMenu>
                    </Dialog>
                </Cell>
                ))}
            </Grid>
        )
    }

    editcardDialog(blogs, user){
        const itemsPerPage = 6; 
        let activeBlogs = blogs.slice (itemsPerPage * this.state.activePage - itemsPerPage, itemsPerPage * this.state.activePage);
        return( 
            <span>
                <a className="btn edit-btn-blog-post" href="#" onClick={this.toggle}  title="Edit Blog">
                    <i className="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
                {activeBlogs.map(({ _id, blog_short_desc, blog_name, blog_desc, blog_image_link, blog_by_author }) => (
                <Modal 
                    isOpen = {this.state.modal && this.state.requiredItem === _id}
                    toggle = {()=>this.toggle(_id)}    
                >
                    <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}  style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}>
                        Edit your blog {this.state.blog_name}
                    </ModalHeader>
                    <ModalBody>
                        <Form onSubmit={e => this.onSubmit(e, this.state._id )}>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Label for="blogHeading">Blog Heading</Label>
                                <Input type="text" name="blog_short_desc" id="blogHeading" placeholder="Update one liner"
                                onChange={this.onTodoChange} value={blog_short_desc}/>
                                 <Label for="blogName">Blog Name</Label>
                                <Input type="text" name="blog_name" id="blogName" placeholder="Update blog name"
                                onChange={this.onTodoChange} value={blog_name}/>
                                <Label for="desc1">Description </Label>
                                <Input type="textarea" name="blog_desc" id="desc1" placeholder="Update your blog"
                                onChange={this.onTodoChange} value={blog_desc}/>
                                 <Label for="imageUrl">Image Url</Label>
                                <Input type="text" name="blog_image_link" id="imageUrl" placeholder="Update image url (Optional)"
                                onChange={this.onTodoChange} value={blog_image_link}/>
                                <Button
                                    color="dark"
                                    style={{marginTop: '2rem'}}
                                    block
                                >Edit blog</Button>
                            </FormGroup>
                        </Form>
                    </ModalBody>
                </Modal>
                ))}
            </span>
        )
    }

    render(){
        const { blogs, loading} = this.props.resume;
        const {  user, isAuthenticated } = this.props.auth;
        const itemsPerPage = 6; 
        let activeBlogs = blogs.slice (itemsPerPage * this.state.activePage - itemsPerPage, itemsPerPage * this.state.activePage);
        return(
            <Container>

            {loading ? (
            <div><Loading/></div>
            ) : (
                <div>
                    {/* blog modal */}
                    <BlogModal />

                    {/* card dialog */}
                    {this.cardDialog(blogs, user)}

                    {this.editcardDialog(blogs, user)}

                    <Grid style={{padding: 0}} id="todo">
                        {activeBlogs.map((item, i) => (
                            <Cell key={item._id} data-id={item._id}>   
                                <Card shadow={5} className="cards-grid">


                                    {item.blog_image_link ?
                                        (<CardTitle style={{color: '#fff', height: '200px',
                                        width: 'auto', backgroundImage: `url(${item.blog_image_link})`, backgroundPosition: 'center',
                                        backgroundSize: 'cover',
                                        backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat'}}></CardTitle>) :

                                        (<CardTitle className="card-title-image"></CardTitle>
                                        )
                                    }

                                    <CardText>
                                        <b>{item.blog_short_desc}</b>
                                    </CardText>

                                    <CardActions border>
                                        <p>
                                        <Button className="blog-read-me-button col-4" onClick={this.handleOpenDialog.bind(this, item._id)}>Read </Button> 

                                        { isAuthenticated && (item.blog_by === user._id) ? 
                                        <span className="col=8">

                                        <Button className="remove-btn-blog-post"
                                        color="danger"
                                        size="sm"
                                        onClick= {this.onDeleteBlogClick.bind(this, item._id)} title="Delete Blog">
                                            &times;
                                        </Button> 
                                        <a className="btn edit-btn-blog-post" href="#" onClick={this.replaceModalItem.bind(this, item._id)}  title="Edit Blog">
                                            <i className="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        </a> 

                                        {/* <a className="btn edit-btn-blog-post" href="#" onClick={this.handleEditOpenDialog.bind(this, item._id)}  title="Edit Blog">
                                            <i className="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        </a> */}

                                        </span> : null }
                                        </p>

                                        <p style={{ fontStyle:'italic', fontWeight:'bold'}}>By-{item.blog_by_author} <span style={{float:'right',}}>{Moment(item.date).format('Do MMMM YYYY')}</span></p> 
                                    </CardActions>
                                </Card>  
                            </Cell>  
                        ))} 
                    </Grid>
                </div> 
                )}
                <Pagination
                    activePage={this.state.activePage}
                    itemsCountPerPage={6}
                    totalItemsCount={blogs.length}
                    pageRangeDisplayed={5}
                    onChange={this.handlePageChange.bind(this)}
                    itemClass='page-item'
                    linkClass='page-link'
                />
            </Container>
        ) 
   }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    resume: state.resume,
    auth: state.auth,
    loading: state.apiCallsInProgress > 0
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getBlog, deleteBlog, updateBlog }) (Blogs);
```

Comment: You can create the State and Function for the Child Component Modal in Blog.js component and pass it as props to Edit.js. Now, you will able to open or close from the parent component

Comment: hi  @JeyanthKanagaraj thank you for your time . but here Modal is opening. but the value which are referencing is always for the the 1st array for every edit.

Comment: In the Edit.js file, while calling the toggle function pass the id to the model state and by default keep the modal as null. And change the `isOpen = {this.state.modal === id}`

Comment: could you please share as an answer . It will be helpful.

Comment: I have updated my code as I missed one edit block whiis actually clicking the button.

Comment: Why are you calling the function `replaceModalItem()` in the parent component if it is defined in the child one?

Comment: I will remove that . might be as i am debugging sometime so thats why i kep it there.

Comment: Actual isue is still there which is unable to figure that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you handle all your posts with your parent component, and use the `<EditBlog /` only as a functinal component. Here is a example and the correponding fiddle:

```
const EditBlog = ({title, content, handleEdit}) => {
return (
                <div classname="editblog">
          <h1>{title}</h1>
          <p>{content}</p>
          <button onClick={handleEdit}>Edit</button>
        </div>
        )
}

class Blog extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state= {
activeBlogs: [
{title: "Heading 1", content: "Content 1"},
{title: "Heading 2", content: "Content 2"}
],
editId: -1,
}
this.handleEdit = this.handleEdit.bind(this);
}

handleEdit(e) {
const {editId, activeBlogs} = this.state;
let newActiveBlogs = [...activeBlogs];
const {name, value } = e.target;
newActiveBlogs[editId]= Object.assign(newActiveBlogs[editId], {[name]: value});
if(editId >= 0) {
this.setState({
activeBlogs: newActiveBlogs
})
}

}
  render() {
  const {activeBlogs, editId} = this.state;
    return (
    <div classname="blog">
    {activeBlogs.map((item, index) => {
        return <EditBlog key={index} {...item} handleEdit={()=>this.setState({editId: index})} />
    })} 
    {editId >= 0 && activeBlogs.length && 
    <div classname="modal">
        <h2>Edit Modal is open</h2>
        <input name="title" value={activeBlogs[editId].title} onChange={this.handleEdit}></input>
        <input name="content" value={activeBlogs[editId].content} onChange={this.handleEdit}></input>
        <button onClick={()=>this.setState({editId:-1})}>Save</button>
    </div>
    }
    </div>
  )
}
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Blog name="Blog" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/votolentino/8jyc90u4/)

Comment: Hi vtolentino thanks for your time. I did n't tried this as I have same way of adding blog i expected to be this working. Everything is working here except corrrect data populating.

Comment: Getting error like .

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `EditBlog`.

Comment: In my case they did not need to be exported because they were all in the same file. Check the fiddle.

Comment: Do you mind if you could look my current code and help me to solve this.

Comment: Sure, you can prepare one jsfiddle with your current status and we can debug it together.

Comment: Now only correct props value for each object are populating. but we need to pass it through state so that it can be modified and submitted.

Comment: Although this issue is not related to the current question. this answer is quite helpful. hence acceptng this as an answer.

Comment: I am glad it helped you.

Comment: Yes it is. but now form values are not editable . It is just passing from props.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one

```
 class EditBlog extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
                this.state = {
                    modal: null,
                    requiredItem : null,
                    _id: '',
                    blog_short_desc: '',
                    blog_name: '',
                    blog_desc: '',
                    blog_image_link: '',
                    blog_by: '',
                    blog_by_author: ''
                };
                this.replaceModalItem = this.replaceModalItem.bind(this);
                this.onTodoChange = this.onTodoChange.bind(this);

            }

        static propTypes = {
            auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
            updateBlog: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
            editBlog: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
            resume: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        }

        UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
            this.setState({
                value: nextProps.name
            })
        }
        toggle = (id) => {
            this.setState({
                modal: id
            });
        }
        componentWillMount() {

            this.props.resume["blogs"].map((blog) => {
                this.setState({
                    updatable : false,
                    _id: blog._id,
                    blog_short_desc: blog.blog_short_desc,
                    blog_name: blog.blog_name,
                    blog_desc: blog.blog_desc,
                    blog_image_link: blog.blog_image_link,
                    blog_by: blog.blog_by,
                    blog_by_author: blog.blog_by_author
                });
            })
        }

        replaceModalItem(id) {
            this.setState({
              openDialog: true,
              OpenEditDialog: true,
              requiredItem: id

            });
        }

        onTodoChange = (e) => {
            this.setState({ 
                [e.target.name] : e.target.value 
            });
        }

        onSubmit = (e, id) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const updatedBlog = {
                blog_short_desc: this.state.blog_short_desc,
                blog_name: this.state.blog_name,
                blog_desc: this.state.blog_desc,
                blog_image_link: this.state.blog_image_link,
                blog_by:  this.props.auth["user"]._id,
                blog_by_author: this.props.auth["user"].name
            }
            //update blog via updateblog action
            this.props.updateBlog(id, updatedBlog, this.props.history);
            alert("Blog updated successfully!");
            //close modal
            e.target.reset();
            this.toggle();
        }
        render(){

            return(
                <span>
       <a className="btn edit-btn-blog-post" href="#" onClick={()=>this.toggle(this.state._id)} title="Edit Blog">
                    <i className="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
                    <Modal 
                        isOpen = {this.state.modal===this.state._id}
                        toggle = {()=>this.toggle(this.state._id)}   
                    >
                        <ModalHeader toggle={()=>this.toggle(this.state._id)} style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}>
                            Edit your blog {this.state.blog_name}
                        </ModalHeader>
                        <ModalBody>
                            <Form onSubmit={e => this.onSubmit(e, this.state._id, )}>
                                <FormGroup>
                                    <Label for="blogHeading">Blog Heading</Label>
                                    <Input type="text" name="blog_short_desc" id="blogHeading" placeholder="Update one liner"
                                    onChange={this.onTodoChange} value={this.state.blog_short_desc}/>
                                     <Label for="blogName">Blog Name</Label>
                                    <Input type="text" name="blog_name" id="blogName" placeholder="Update blog name"
                                    onChange={this.onTodoChange} value={this.state.blog_name}/>
                                    <Label for="desc1">Description </Label>
                                    <Input type="textarea" name="blog_desc" id="desc1" placeholder="Update your blog"
                                    onChange={this.onTodoChange} value={this.state.blog_desc}/>
                                     <Label for="imageUrl">Image Url</Label>
                                    <Input type="text" name="blog_image_link" id="imageUrl" placeholder="Update image url (Optional)"
                                    onChange={this.onTodoChange} value={this.state.blog_image_link}/>
                                    <Button
                                        color="dark"
                                        style={{marginTop: '2rem'}}
                                        block
                                    >Edit blog</Button>
                                </FormGroup>
                            </Form>
                        </ModalBody>
                    </Modal>
                </span>
            )
        }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
        resume: state.resume,
        auth: state.auth
    })

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, { updateBlog })(EditBlog);
```

Comment: Do we need to include this or no as this will click the button.

<a className="btn edit-btn-blog-post" href="#" onClick={this.toggle} title="Edit Blog">
                    <i className="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>

Comment: you need to include this

Comment: No its not togelling the modal.

Comment: my current code which is togelling and working is updated .

Comment: No I missed the `a` tag here in the code above. this code is same which populating the 1st array.

Comment: U have missed that `a` tag which is above `modal` which calls the onclick.

Comment: Got it, just a sec

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212235/discussion-between-tanmoy-sarkar-and-jeyanth-kanagaraj).

Comment: no. Currnt code is also breaking the closing action. now modal is not closing.